# Modifying a list of matrices with conditional statement

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have a list of around 100 matrices, that looks like this

```
A={{{425060., 2.14235*10^6, 0.49, 0.01, 0.38, 0.620161, 
   20.}, {1.24808*10^6, 1.53025*10^6, 0.04, 0.07, 0.31, 0.320312, 
   20.}, {7.39304*10^6, 1.40204*10^6, 0.83, 0.45, 0.09, 0.94842, 20.} .... {4.27537*10^6, 
 1.62124*10^6, 0.24, 0.28, 0.62, 0.721388, 20.1}, {3.27776*10^6, 
 2.25816*10^6, 0.01, 0.21, 0.72, 0.750067, 20.1}, {3.0814*10^6, 
 1.95624*10^6, 0.02, 0.19, 0.72, 0.744916, 20.1}, {2.42706*10^6, 
 1.25729*10^6, 0.03, 0.17, 0.7, 0.720972, 20.1}, {4.47196*10^6, 
 1.23247*10^6, 0.24, 0.27, 0.57, 0.674833, 20.1}, {1.57132*10^7, 
 1.65019*10^6, 0.76, 0.92, 0.5, 1.29383, 20.1} ......
```

Each matrix has an unknown number of rows. Each matrix holds information about a group of particles at a given time. Columns 3,4,5 are the x,y and z coordinate of each particle. For each matrix, I want to compare the Euclidean distance between every two particles, and keep the particle whose distance from all other particles in that matrix is greater than 0.01. I want to use the following algorithm, I pick a matrix, then pick its first row, then I check whether EuclideanDistance[{#3, #4, #5}, {from all other particles}]> 0.01 then that row (that particle) gets copied into another matrix, if not, then ignore both the elements for further computation. This way a new list of matrix will be created with particles which are at least 0.01 units away from each other.

EDIT : I am getting error messages EuclideanDistance::argr: EuclideanDistance called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. >> Pick::incomp: Expressions {{1.13266*10^7,1.40618*10^6,0.82,0.67,0.35,1.11526,22.7}} and {EuclideanDistance[{0.82,0.67,0.35}]>0.01} have incompatible shapes. >> EuclideanDistance::argr: EuclideanDistance called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. >> Pick::incomp: Expressions {{1.13266*10^7,1.38136*10^6,0.82,0.67,0.35,1.11526,22.8}} and {EuclideanDistance[{0.82,0.67,0.35}]>0.01} have incompatible shapes

this is happening when there is only one element in the matrix, as `EuclideanDistance` requires two arguments. Is there any way I can have the Euclidean distance skip over these single elements, yet the fina list of matrices will have those single elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking one the matrices out of your 100, say

```
aA = {{4.27537*10^6, 1.62124*10^6, 0.24, 0.28, 0.62, 0.721388, 20.1}, 
      {3.27776*10^6, 2.25816*10^6, 0.01, 0.21, 0.72, 0.750067, 20.1},
      {3.0814*10^6, 1.95624*10^6, 0.02, 0.19, 0.72, 0.744916,  20.1}, 
      {2.42706*10^6, 1.25729*10^6, 0.03, 0.17, 0.7, 0.720972,  20.1}, 
      {4.47196*10^6, 1.23247*10^6, 0.24, 0.27, 0.57, 0.674833, 20.1}, 
      {1.57132*10^7, 1.65019*10^6, 0.76, 0.92, 0.5, 1.29383,   20.1}};
```

Create a `Nearest` function for the matrix based on columns `{3,4,5}`:

```
nf = Nearest[aA[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]];
```

so that

```
nf[u, 2]
```

gives the two elements that are closest to `u`; one of the those two is, of course, `u`.

Then, for a threshold distance `t`

```
Pick[aA, EuclideanDistance @@ nf[#, 2] > t & /@ aA[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]]
```

picks the elements of the matrix whose `{x,y,z}` coordinates are at least `t` distance far from the `{x,y,z}` coordinates of the other elements.

```
t = .03;
Pick[aA, EuclideanDistance @@ nf[#, 2] > t & /@ aA[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]]
```

> {{4.27537*10^6, 1.62124*10^6, 0.24, 0.28, 0.62, 0.721388, 20.1}, 
>         {4.47196*10^6, 1.23247*10^6, 0.24, 0.27, 0.57, 0.674833, 20.1}, 
>         {1.57132*10^7, 1.65019*10^6, 0.76, 0.92, 0.5, 1.29383, 20.1}}

Note: You could also use

```
Select[aA, (EuclideanDistance @@ nf[#[[{3, 4, 5}]], 2] > t) &]
(* same output *)
```

**Update:** a function that can be `Map`ped to the entire list of matrices:

```
ClearAll[pF];
pF[t_] := With[{nfunc = Nearest[#[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]], mat = #},
    Pick[mat, EuclideanDistance @@ nfunc[#, 2] > t & /@ mat[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]]] &;
```

Example:

```
pF[.03] @ aA
(* same result as above *)

aB = {{425060., 2.14235*10^6, 0.49, 0.01, 0.38, 0.620161, 20.}, 
      {1.24808*10^6, 1.53025*10^6, 0.04, 0.07, 0.31, 0.320312, 20.}, 
      {7.39304*10^6, 1.40204*10^6, 0.83, 0.45, 0.09, 0.94842,  20.}}; 

A={aB,aA};

result = pF[.03] /@ A;
TableForm[TableForm /@ result, TableSpacing -> 3 ]
```

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant! thank you. Is there a way I can automatically do this for all the matrices in the list instead of doing it one by one?

Comment: @NilanjanBanik, thank you for the Accept. Updated with a function that can be used with a list of matrices.

Comment: I am getting error messages EuclideanDistance::argr: EuclideanDistance called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. >>

Pick::incomp: Expressions {{1.13266*10^7,1.40618*10^6,0.82,0.67,0.35,1.11526,22.7}} and {EuclideanDistance[{0.82,0.67,0.35}]>0.01} have incompatible shapes. >>

EuclideanDistance::argr: EuclideanDistance called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. >>

Pick::incomp: Expressions {{1.13266*10^7,1.38136*10^6,0.82,0.67,0.35,1.11526,22.8}} and {EuclideanDistance[{0.82,0.67,0.35}]>0.01} have incompatible shapes. >>

Comment: Ah I just found out why, because those matrices have only one row.

Comment: Is there any way I can have the Euclidean distance skip over these single elements, yet the final list of matrices will have those single elements?

Comment: @HuShu, does it work if you use `pF2` instead of `pF` where  `ClearAll[pF2];
pF2[t_] :=  With[{nfunc = Nearest[#[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]], mat = #}, 
    If[Length@mat <= 1, mat,   Pick[mat, EuclideanDistance @@ nfunc[#, 2] > t & /@  mat[[All, {3, 4, 5}]]]]] &;`?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!